# cakephp getting data from different model

Tags: cakephp

I'm new to cakephp and I've a problem with building my application. In my application I have the models called Customer , Job, Jobtask, Jobtasksvehicle and Vehicle. Their database relationship is  Customer->Job->Jobtask->Jobtasksvehicle->Vehicle.
I have a page called job sheet, in that sheet I've to display customer name, job id, job task, and vehicle name. I can get customer name, job id and job task display but I cannot figure out how to display vehicle name in there. Can anyone help me.

This is the model for the page

```
    function sch($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid job', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->set('job', $this->Job->read(null, $id));
```

I want to display vehicle name in this table

```
<div class="related">

<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($job['Jobtask'] as $jobtask):
        $class = null;
        if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
            $class = ' class="altrow"';
        }
    ?>
    <tr<?php echo $class;?>>
        <td><?php echo $jobtask['id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $jobtask['job_id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $jobtask['rate_id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $jobtask['type'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $jobtask['date'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $jobtask['starttime'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $jobtask['timeband'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $jobtask['settlement'];?></td>       
        <td><?php echo $job['Jobtasksvehicle']['vehicle_id'];?></td>    

        <td class="actions">



            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Allocate Vehicle', true), array('controller' => 'jobtasksvehicles','action' => 'add', $jobtask['id'])); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View', true), array('controller' => 'jobtasks', 'action' => 'view', $jobtask['id'])); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit', true), array('controller' => 'jobtasks', 'action' => 'edit', $jobtask['id'])); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Delete', true), array('controller' => 'jobtasks', 'action' => 'delete', $jobtask['id']), null, sprintf(__('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', true), $jobtask['id'])); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

This is the relationship betweens models

Customer hasMany Job

Job belongsTo Customer

Job hasMany Jobtask

Jobtask belongsTo Job

Jobtask hasMany Jobtasksvehicle

Jobtasksvehicle belongsTo Jobtask and Vehicle

Vehicle hasMany Jobtasksvehicle

Comment: post your exact relations ($hasMany, $belongsTo...). And this is not a good approach as you will be returning potentially massive amounts of data. You should look in to [Containable behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable) as a better option, selecting only what you need.

Comment: I've edited the relationship between models.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Containable behaviour as Ross mentions is the best approach. Add to your Job model:

```
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

And in your controller:

```
$job = $this->Job->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Job.id' => $id),
    'contain' => array(
        'Jobtask' => array(
            'Jobtasksvehicle' => array(
                'Vehicle'
             ),
         ),
    ),
));
$this->set(compact('job'));
```

See the [Containable documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable) for more help. I'll leave the wrangling of data in the view up to you.

Comment: I've done as u posted, I've got Job, Jobtasks, Customer details display but i cannot get vehicle details display. I tried like this and its not working 

        <td>
   <?php echo $this->Html->link($job['Vehicle']['vehiclemodel'], array('controller' => 'vehicles', 'action' => 'view', $job['Vehicle']['vehiclemodel'])); ?>
  </td>